# Python Tkinter radiobutton program debugging

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

Essentially the program is a group of radio buttons and when the user clicks the submit button, the program should return the answer matching the string of choices made by the user. I've gotten it to work for the most part, but the decision made in the end is still wrong. Let me know if I can answer anymore questions.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox


root = Tk()

q1 = IntVar()

Label(root,
      text="""How many samples do you have?""",
      justify = LEFT,
      padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
            text="One",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q1,
            value=1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
            text="Two",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q1,
            value=2).pack(anchor=W)


q2 = IntVar()

Label(root,
      text="""Which choice most closely fits your sample size?""",
      justify = LEFT,
      padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """Less than 30""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q2,
            value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """Greater than or equal to 30""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q2,
            value = 2).pack(anchor =W)



q3 = IntVar()

Label(root,
      text="""Is the population mean known?""",
      justify = LEFT,
      padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """Yes""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q3,
            value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """No""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q3,
            value = 2).pack(anchor=W)


q4 = IntVar()

Label(root,
      text="""Is the standard deviation of your data known?""",
      justify = LEFT,
      padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """Yes""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q4,
            value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """No""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q4,
            value = 2).pack(anchor =W)


q5 = IntVar()

Label(root,
      text="""Do you wish to compare two groups?""",
      justify = LEFT,
      padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """Yes""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q5,
            value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """No""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q5,
            value = 2).pack(anchor =W)


q6 = IntVar()

Label(root,
      text="""Do you want to compare two sample means?""",
      justify = LEFT,
      padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """Yes""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q6,
            value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """No""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q6,
            value = 2).pack(anchor =W)




q7 = IntVar()

Label(root,
      text="""Is your data paired (E.g. before and after data)?""",
      justify = LEFT,
      padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """Yes""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q7,
            value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """No""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q7,
            value = 2).pack(anchor =W)



q8 = IntVar()

Label(root,
      text="""Are you testing proportions?""",
      justify = LEFT,
      padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """Yes""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q8,
            value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """No""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q8,
            value = 2).pack(anchor =W)



q9 = IntVar()

Label(root,
      text="""Do you wish to test for a difference between observed and expected data?""",
      justify = LEFT,
      padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """Yes""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q9,
            value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
            text = """No""",
            padx = 20,
            variable=q9,
            value = 2).pack(anchor =W)


Button(root, text = "Submit", command=choose).pack()

def choose():
    if q1 == 1 and q2 == 1 and q3 == 2 and q4 == 2 and  q5 == 1 and q6 == 2 and q7 == 2 and q8 == 2 and q9 == 2 :
        tkMessageBox.showinfo( 'You should use the t-test!')

    elif q1 == 1 and q2 == 2 and q3 == 1 and q4 == 1 and q5 == 2 and q6 == 2 and q7 == 2 and  q8 == 2 and q9 == 2:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('You should use the z-test!')

    elif q1 == 1 and q2 == 1 and q3 == 2 and q4 == 2 and q5 == 1 and q6 == 2 and q7 == 1 and q8 == 2 and q9 == 2:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo( 'You should use the paired t-test!')

    elif q1 == 2 and q2 == 1 and q3 == 2 and q4 == 2 and q5 == 1 and q6 == 1 and q7 == 2 and q8 == 2 and q9 == 2:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo( 'You should use the two-sample t-test!')

    elif q1 == 2 and q2 == 2 and q3 == 1 and q4 == 1 and q5 == 2 and q6 == 1 and q7 == 2 and q8 == 2 and q9 == 2:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('You should use the two-sample z-test!')

    elif q1 == 1 and q2 == 2 and q3 == 1 and q4 == 1 and q5 == 2 and q6 == 2 and q7 == 2 and q8 == 1 and q9 == 2:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('You should use the 1-prop z-test!')

    elif q1 == 2 and q2 == 2 and q3 == 1 and q4 == 1 and q5 == 2 and q6 == 2 and q7 == 2 and q8 == 1 and q9 == 2:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('You should use the 2-prop z-test!')

    elif q1 == 1 and q2 == 2 and q3 == 2 and q4 == 2 and q5 == 2 and q6 == 2 and q7 == 2 and q8 == 2 and q9 == 1:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo( 'You should use the chi-square test!')

    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo('You have either incorrectly answered a question about your data or none of the available tests are appropriate.')
        sys.exit()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `get` method when comparing `Intvar` instances and you need two arguments for your `tkMessageBox.showinfo(title, message)` function instead your passing only the title with no message so change your code to look like:

```
if q1.get() == 1 and q2.get() == 1 and q3.get() == 2 and q4.get() == 2 and  q5.get() == 1 and q6.get() == 2 and q7.get() == 2 and q8.get() == 2 and q9.get() == 2 :
    tkMessageBox.showinfo('Info','You should use the t-test!')
```

and also don't use `sys.exit()` to exit you program it will cause your program to be unresponsive instead use `root.destroy()`

Hopefully your message boxes should now be working as expected!

[image]

*optional: use `tkMessageBox.showerror(title, message)` to display error messages*

Comment: Thanks! I did that and I'm still getting the same issue, even if I follow the decision path in the if statement completely, it always prints out the final else statement. Even though I should be getting a different answer. What could be my problem?

Comment: @kellie92 updated answer BTW I don't get what you mean by your still getting the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

You should allow for not found conditions.  Also lists make it easier to understand IMHO.  The following should be self-explanatory.  It only tests for the first 2 conditions with a third option for an easy test of the code, with print statements added for testing.  You can expand from there.  Also the use of lists or a function will greatly reduce the amount of "Label, Button, and Button" code.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox


def compare_lists(q_list, results_list):
    """ see if the radio buttons are in one of the results
        If so, return the number of the matching list
    """
    for ctr, sub_list in enumerate(results_list):
        if sub_list == q_list:
            print "Found", ctr, sub_list
            return ctr
    return -1

def choose():
    q_list = []
    results_list = [[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                    [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                    [1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1]]
    print_list = ['You should use the t-test!',
                  'You should use the z-test!',
                  'Testing Only']
    for var in (q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9):
        q_list.append(var.get())
    print q_list

    ## ctr = number of matching list and will print
    ## the same number in the print list
    ctr = compare_lists(q_list, results_list)
    if ctr > -1:
        result_label.set(print_list[ctr])
    else:
        result_label.set('Combination not found')

root = Tk()

q1 = IntVar()

Label(root,
      text="""How many samples do you have?""",
      justify = LEFT,
      padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
        text="One",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q1,
        value=1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
        text="Two",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q1,
        value=2).pack(anchor=W)


q2 = IntVar()

Label(root,
  text="""Which choice most closely fits your sample size?""",
  justify = LEFT,
  padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """Less than 30""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q2,
        value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """Greater than or equal to 30""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q2,
        value = 2).pack(anchor =W)



q3 = IntVar()

Label(root,
  text="""Is the population mean known?""",
  justify = LEFT,
  padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """Yes""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q3,
        value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """No""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q3,
        value = 2).pack(anchor=W)


q4 = IntVar()

Label(root,
  text="""Is the standard deviation of your data known?""",
  justify = LEFT,
  padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """Yes""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q4,
        value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """No""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q4,
        value = 2).pack(anchor =W)


q5 = IntVar()

Label(root,
  text="""Do you wish to compare two groups?""",
  justify = LEFT,
  padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """Yes""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q5,
        value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """No""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q5,
        value = 2).pack(anchor =W)


q6 = IntVar()

Label(root,
  text="""Do you want to compare two sample means?""",
  justify = LEFT,
  padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """Yes""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q6,
        value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """No""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q6,
        value = 2).pack(anchor =W)




q7 = IntVar()

Label(root,
  text="""Is your data paired (E.g. before and after data)?""",
  justify = LEFT,
  padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """Yes""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q7,
        value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """No""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q7,
        value = 2).pack(anchor =W)



q8 = IntVar()

Label(root,
  text="""Are you testing proportions?""",
  justify = LEFT,
  padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """Yes""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q8,
        value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """No""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q8,
        value = 2).pack(anchor =W)



q9 = IntVar()

Label(root,
  text="""Do you wish to test for a difference between observed and expected data?""",
  justify = LEFT,
  padx = 20).pack()

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """Yes""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q9,
        value = 1).pack(anchor=W)

Radiobutton(root,
        text = """No""",
        padx = 20,
        variable=q9,
        value = 2).pack(anchor =W)


result_label = StringVar()
result_label.set("")
Label(root, textvariable=result_label, fg="red").pack()
Button(root, text = "Submit", command=choose, fg="blue", bg="white").pack()
Button(root, text = "EXIT", command=root.quit,
       bg="blue", fg="yellow").pack()

root.mainloop()
```